# kotlin exception thrown in android library shown as warning instead of error

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, runtime-error, logcat

i am working on an android library written in kotlin and in it i want to throw an exception. lets say my library contains a function that takes an `Int` as parameter and the number 2 is illegal for whatever reason... so i would have:

```
fun doSomething(value: Int)
{
    if(value == 2)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("the number 2 is not allowed in this function")
    else
        //do something
}
```

i would expect that if i call `doSomething(2)` the following will happen:

1. the exception would show as an **error** in logcat.
2. the app would crash.

however instead, the exception in logcat is shown as a **warning** and the app does not crash.

why is this happening? how can i get the exception to show as an error?

Comment: Are you sure that the app that you use to test your library doesn't cause this behavior?

Comment: What thread are you calling it from? In general, only exceptions on the main thread crash the whole app.

Comment: @PiotrK what do you mean? how would that happen? i am using a separate module in the same project to test and i am simply calling `doSomething(2)`

Comment: @RobPridham i tried both main thread and background thread. but even if background thread would not crash the app, why does it appear as warning and not error in logcat?

Comment: I think what Piotr means is that it's possible that the enclosing application is catching the exception (e.g. a try/catch block) and then outputting it to LogCat as a warning.

Comment: @RobPridham that is not the case as i am the one testing the library and i am not catching the exception or logging it in my test module

Comment: Are you testing it in a native app that you've written entirely yourself, or in some sort of framework/container?

Comment: @RobPridham in the same project i have 2 modules. one for the library and one "app" module for testing (written entirely myself in native code).